# Getting also column names

Tags: php, json

I'm retrieving some data from a database and convert it into JSON:

```
if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        $json['results'][]=$row;
    }
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

This is the result:

```
{"results":
 [["1","0","123","456",null],
 ["2","0","567","978",null]]
}
```

But I also need the column names.

When I change it to `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, I get the following response in my console:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

Comment: You need to [edit] this question to add more details. What is `$query`? What are the column names? How do you *want* the JSON to be structured?

Comment: The second output doesn't appear to be from the code you posted above. Please post more code in the second example.

Comment: `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}` looks like an AJAX status and nothing to do with your PHP code. So I would assume when you change the PHP you introduce an error, as normally your JSON String would be in `"responseText":"",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_row` produces a numerically indexed array, if you want names of the database columns i.e. an associative array use `$result->fetch_assoc()`

Also its a good idea to maintain a little status info in the json structure you are passing back to the form so you can see what has happened during the PHP execution from an AJAX call.

This is just a simple example for use during development

```
$json = array();
$json['status']['info'] = "Started";
$json['status']['count'] = 0;

if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
    $json['status']['info'] = "Query OK";

    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $json['status']['count'] = $json['status']['count'] + 1;
        $json['results'][] = $row;
    }
} else {  
    // added so you get to see an error message if query fails
    $json['status']['mysqlerror'] = $link->error;
}

echo json_encode($json);
exit;
```

This output you say you get

```
  {"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

Is a basic header response from the PHP script, you see that `"responseText":""` is empty, thats where the json string would normally go. So I have to assume when you amended the PHP code you introduced an error somehow.

> Also, you start your code using the OOP style of mysqli i.e. `$link->query($query)` but then you go to the proceedural style i.e. `mysqli_fetch_row($result)` While this is actually legal, it is a good idea to stick with either the OOP style or the Proceedural style all the way through your code, if only for readability in 2 days or 2 weeks when you come back to amend a piece of code.